# parsing json to check whether a field is blank in bash

Tags: json, bash, shell

So, lets say, I am trying to write a shell script which does the following:

```
1) Ping http://localhost:8088/query?key=q1
2) It returns a json response :
    {
"status": "success", 
"result": []
 "query": "q1"
  }
or
{
"status": "success", 
"result": ["foo"], 
"artist_key": "q1"
```

}

The "result" is either an empty array or filled array.. 
I am trying to write a shell script which is checking whether "result" is empty list or not?

Comment: Use `curl` + [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a language that can convert JSON to a native data structure:

```
wget -O- "http://localhost:8088/query?key=q1" |
perl -MJSON -0777 -ne '
    $data = decode_json $_;
    exit (@{$data->{result}} == 0)
'
```

That exits with a success status if the result attribute is NOT empty.  Encapsulating into a shell function:

```
check_result() {
    wget -O- "http://localhost:8088/query?key=q1" |
    perl -MJSON -0777 -ne '$data = decode_json $_; exit (@{$data->{result}} == 0)'
}

if check_result; then 
    echo result is NOT empty
else
    echo result is EMPTY
fi
```

---

I like ruby for parsing JSON:

```
ruby -rjson -e 'data = JSON.parse(STDIN.read); exit (data["result"].length > 0)'
```

It's interesting that the exit status requires the opposite comparison operator. I guess ruby will convert `exit(true)` to `exit(0)`, unlike perl which has no true boolean objects only integers.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work:

```
# Assume result is from curl, but could be in a file or whatever
if curl "http://localhost:8088/query?key=q1" | grep -Pq '"result":\s+\[".+"\]'; then
    echo "has result"
else
    echo "does not have result"
fi
```

However, I'm assuming these are on separate lines. If not, there are linters for format it.

Edited (based on the jq comment), here's a jq solution as suggested by  Adrian Frühwirth:

```
result=$( curl "http://localhost:8088/query?key=q1" | jq '.result' )
if [ "$result" == "[]" ]; then
    echo "does not have result"
else
    echo "has result"
fi
```

I have learned something new today. And as I play around with this more, maybe it's better to do this:

```
result=$( curl "http://localhost:8088/query?key=q1" | jq '.result | has(0)' )
if [ "$result" == "true" ]; then
    echo "has result"
else
    echo "does not have result"
fi
```

See the [manual](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). I wasn't able to get the `-e` or `--exit-status` arguments to work.

Comment: Instead of curl, can i use wget?

Comment: You could use wget as in the other answer or whatnot. Arguably, using perl or ruby or phython to actually parse the JSON is a better solution, but if you wants bash, I gives you bash.